# Why this leaks on a rotation?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I came across the following memory leak example

```
package com.justinschultz.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LeakedDialogActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        builder.setMessage("This dialog leaks!").setTitle("Leaky Dialog").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it leaks on a rotation. I understand, a new Activity is created while the dialog is still on screen (containing a reference to the old activity). Suppose you close the dialog and rotate again. Shouldn't the reference to the oldest activity be gone, thus allowing the memory to be reclaimed?

Comment: Are you sure there is a memory leak?  Did you check heap growth?

Comment: Yup, it is, according to LogCat. I found this example [here](http://publicstaticdroidmain.com/2012/01/avoiding-android-memory-leaks-part-1/). I sort of understand why it's a leak, but I think the gc can reclaim it after the user closes the dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AlertDialogs (if used outside of Fragments) should be instantiated through `onCreateDialog()`/`showDialog()` to avoid leaks.

This implementation is deprecated and should be replaced by a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), but will work for you:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    showDialog(YOUR_DIALOG_ID);
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {
    case YOUR_DIALOG_ID:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(LeakedDialogActivity.this)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setMessage("This dialog leaks!")
        .setTitle("Leaky Dialog")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
        })
        .create();
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

---

**ADDED**

When you don't create a dialog in `onCreateDialog` its essentially not attached to (or owned by) the Activity, and therefore, it's lifecycle. When the Activity is destroyed or recreated, the Dialog maintains a reference to it.

In theory, the Dialog should not leak if you use `setOwnerActivity()` and dismiss in `onPause()` (I believe).

I'm not sure you have to worry much about this *gotcha* as far as general leaks go. Dialogs are kind of a special case.

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for the response! The example I posted is just "pedagogical". I was hoping to find out the cause of the leak so I can avoid leak-prone practices.